# io.Copy in goroutine to prevent blocking

Tags: go

I'm reading the book "Black Hat Go". I have come upon an example of a simple TCP proxy. It basically just forwards on a request and sends back a reply. The gist of the proxy code looks like this (modified):

```
func handle(src net.Conn) {
    dst, err := net.Dial("tcp", "example.com:80")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Unable to connect to remote")
    }
    defer dst.Close()

    // Run in goroutine to prevent io.Copy from blocking
    go func() {
        if _, err := io.Copy(dst, src); err != nil {
            log.Fatalln("Something wrong src -> dst")
        }
    }()

    if _, err := io.Copy(src, dst); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Something wrong dst -> src")
    }
}
```

The portion I don't understand is the comment "Run in goroutine to prevent io.Copy from blocking". I've run it both with and without wrapping it in a goroutine, and it works only with a goroutine, but I don't understand why. Couldn't we run one blocking `io.Copy` for the request, followed by another for the response? I guess I'm having trouble understanding how we can guarantee ordering if the first `io.Copy` is run in a goroutine.

Comment: TCP is a duplex stream; there are no "requests" and "responses", so you cannot copy one then the other.

Comment: I understand TCP, but I guess you got to the heart of my problem. I was thinking about working with the encapsulated HTTP packets rather than forwarding the entirety of the stream. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're dealing with a TCP stream, you have to deal with traffic going both ways, from src to dest and from dest to src. You can do that with two copy operations. However, copy will block until it receives error or EOF (i.e. socket close), so you have to put at least one of those copy operations to a goroutine. The way it is written, one copy operation will read from one socket and write the the other, and the other copy operation will do the reverse until an error or EOF. When an error or EOF is received, both copy operations will stop.

Answer (score 1):

The io.Copy function returns after the reader or writer return an error (including io.EOF).  If the io.Copy call is not run in the Go routine, then all data is copied from src to dst before any data is copied from dst to src.